# Ad has an incorrect 'source'

Tags: bug, advertising

This ad, **on Code Review**:

[image]

links to:

```
http://engine.adzerk.net/r?e=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&s=MFHwMALcxHB2XRwa6p5otO7Go04&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftridion.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F13151%2Fcontent-porter-primary-key-constraint-pk-file-extensions-error%3Futm_medium%3Dad%26utm_source%3Dhttp-skeptics-stackexchange-com-questions-1700-do-bigger-or-more-monitors-incr%26utm_campaign%3Dtridion.stackexchange.com-promo%26utm_content%3D13151
```

which redirects to:

```
http://tridion.stackexchange.com/?utm_medium=ad&utm_source=http-skeptics-stackexchange-com-questions-1700-do-bigger-or-more-monitors-incr&utm_campaign=tridion.stackexchange.com-promo&utm_content=13151
```

You can see `utm_source=http-skeptics-stackexchange-com-questions-1700-do-bigger-or-more-monitors-incr`. I presume `utm_source` is the originating site (ie. the site the ad was clicked on from), so why is it saying I clicked on it from Skeptics rather than Code Review?

I don't think this actually matters but I'm curious: Why is it happening? Is there a reason? (If so, why? :)

Comment: @Shadow yep, nice find! Again ;)